# apache2 tomcat6 single instance or multiple instances

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-9.10, tomcat6

I have apache tomcat servers(ubuntu 9.10) hosting jsp pages. Each server has two virtual hosting and is setup in apache and tomcat configuration files. Developers are in a plan to add two more jsp applications on each server i.e each server should host four jsp pages. I could not decide whether a tomcat(single instance) can handle four virtual hosting or I should use multiple tomcat instances(two app for an instance). I could not decide myself that which way is best as I don't have much experience on this and hope anyone can help me here in choosing the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple instance of Tomcat. Generally this is done for running a different jsp application independently and creating a load balancer server.

Comment: Could you tell me why? and why not single instance?

Comment: independent and minimal overhead